What tools should I use to create the liquid metal effect of the T-1000?
I am a blender beginner and a fan of the Terminator movies. I'm going to create an illustration of the T-1000, but how can I create the liquid metal effect?


You'll have to [edit] your question to get a helpful answer here.  The question is tagged materials, but what precisely are you unhappy with in your current result?  How would you compare it to the original and what do you think is missing?

Is your question how to model morphing mesh to appear like soft liquid? Or is your question how to make a material that reflects like shiny metal?

Thanks for the reminder!  My question is how to simulate a deformed mesh so that it looks like a soft liquid!
